# Microsoft Cognitive Services Face API : FaceNotFound while using Verify API

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Following are the steps

Create a Person and add Face 
Like to register person details and ensure the Face Id is persisted

Step 1. faceServiceClient.CreatePersonGroupAsync(groupId, groupName);

Step 2. p.PersonId = _faceServiceClient.CreatePersonAsync(groupId, p.Name).Result.PersonId;

Step 3. 
var persistPersonFaceID = _faceServiceClient.AddPersonFaceAsync(groupId, p.PersonId, fStream).Result.PersistedFaceId;

Step 4. _faceServiceClient.TrainPersonGroupAsync(groupID);

Now, like to authenticate a person using the Image provided

Step a 
var DetectedFaceID = _faceServiceClient.DetectAsync(firstFilestream, true, true).Result.FaceId;

Step b.. 
var res = _faceServiceClient.VerifyAsync(persistPersonFaceID, DetectedFaceID).Result;

On the call to VerifyAsync, It throws and error like following
{"error":{"code":"FaceNotFound","message":"Face '7a89ace1-a4b7-4c08-b718-4fec0e9e89d5' is not found."}}

Please do let me know if any of the above needs to be corrected

Possible Issues: 
A persistPersonFaceID belongs to a group and I am trying to compare the face id which was retrieved by using Detect. If this is a problem, can you please suggest a resolution

Answer (score 2):

`/verify` only takes faceIds currently, not persistedFaceIds you're getting back after persisting to a person object.

If I've understood your scenario correctly, you can use either `/findsimiliars` or `/identify` since you're persisting the known face.

With `/identify` you'd pass in `DetectedFaceID` and specify the `groupId` ([API reference for /identify](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395239))

Adding this support for `verify` is something being planned and if you wouldn't mind I'd encourage you to add some votes to it on uservoice: [/verify should also take persistedFaceIds](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/356325-apis/suggestions/14913210--verify-should-take-persistedfaceids)

Comment: Thanks for reply

As of our requirement we have authenticated the user already and so we aware the person and his details along with the PersistedFaceID (as we plan to store them on our end)
Plan to use FaceAPI.Verify to re-confirm the Authenticated user